# how to code client / server communication in J2ME?

Tags: java-me, client-server, java

I am developing a project that exchanges data between client and server. I have coded it in J2SE but I don't know how to make it work in J2ME?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you're in need for something highlevel, just use plain sockets. Here are some links to get you started:

- [Java Midp API: `SocketConnection`](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/io/SocketConnection.html)
- [Network Programming with J2ME Wireless Devices](http://www.wirelessdevnet.com/channels/java/features/j2me_http.phtml)
- [Client Server in J2ME (Socket Programming sample)](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=738)
- [Network Programming with MIDP 2.0](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/midp2network/)

Comment: Note, however, that sockets are not available on all devices. Many carriers block connections to anything but port 80 (for HTTP) or port 443 (for HTTPS). If you want something truly portable, use HTTP as your transport, not raw sockets.